# how do i generate access token for listing all collaborators of a github api using python script

Tags: python, github, token

Below is my python script to print all the collaborators of a Github repository. I am getting a Response 403 error. I don't know which token should i use here. Is it the personal token, OAuth token. Can someone please guide me how to generate a access token here?

```
# coding: utf-8

import requests
import sys
import json
from pprint import pprint
import codecs

#sys.stdout = codecs.getwriter("utf-8")(sys.stdout)
headers = {'Accept':'application/vnd.github.hellcat-preview+json'}
LIST_REPOSITORIES_API = 'https://api.github.com/repos/d3/d3'
LIST_COLLABORATORS_API = 'https://api.github.com/repos/%s/collaborators'

if __name__ == '__main__':

  headers['Authorization'] = 'token %s' % 'my_token'

  # get repositories
  res = requests.get(LIST_REPOSITORIES_API)
  print(res)
  repos = res.json()

  # get collaborators
  repos2collaborators = []
  collaborators2repos = {}
  print(type(repos))
  print(repos)
  full_name = repos['full_name']
  print(full_name)

  #res1 = requests.get(LIST_COLLABORATORS_API, headers=headers)
  #print(res1)

  res = requests.get(LIST_COLLABORATORS_API % full_name, headers=headers)
  print(res)
```

Comment: https://blog.github.com/2013-05-16-personal-api-tokens/ or https://developer.github.com/v3/#authentication ?

Comment: @DeliriousLettuce Thanks for your response. I generated the personal access token and tried using it in my code. I am getting the same error.

Comment: I tried to do this and I also got a 403 but there is a fairly clear message that comes along with it, `"Must have push access to view repository collaborators."`.

Comment: The above script works only if you are added as a collaborator in the repository. If you are not added as a collaborator then the code will return a 403 Response which means you are not authorized to access the repository.